# free abelian group of two generators

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is this the way to express the free abelian group of two generators is {$\alpha,\beta|\alpha \beta\alpha^{-1}\beta^{-1}=e$}.

How to prove that the free abelian group of two generators is $\mathbb {Z} × \mathbb {Z}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A free abelian group on a set $\,X\,$ is one generated by $\,X\,$ and subject *only* to the axioms of abelian group theory, which is **exactly** what happens with

$$\{\alpha\,,\,\beta\;;\;\alpha\beta\alpha^{-1}\beta^{-1}=1\}\;,\;X:=\{\alpha\,,\,\beta\}$$

Note that $\,\alpha\beta\alpha^{-1}\beta^{-1}=1\iff\alpha\beta=\beta\alpha\,$ .

Comment: the only thing is confusing me that how to see that $\alpha \alpha =1, \beta \beta=1$?

Comment: Why do you think you'd see that, @Danial ? Do you expect it or what?

Comment: aha ,, now i understand ,, i thought it is $\mathbb{Z}_2 × \mathbb{Z}_2$  I am sorry, and thank you very much :)

Comment: Good @Danial. BTW, the only *finite* free group is the trivial one.

Comment: The emphatic "exactly" in the answer perhaps deserves a word of explanation. The axioms of abelian group theory require *all* elements of the group to commute; the equation in the presentation only says that the two generators, $\alpha$ and $\beta$, commute. So we're tacitly using the fact that, when the generators commute, it automatically follows that all the other elements commute as well.